# Generating Random Number In Each Row In Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select all rows of a table followed by a random number between 1 to 9:

```
select t.*, (select dbms_random.value(1,9) num from dual) as RandomNumber
from myTable t
```

But the random number is the same from row to row, only different from each run of the query. How do I make the number different from row to row in the same execution?

Comment: Just to be clear, the `dbms_random.value()` call is only executed once, since the `select` it's in is evaluated before the outer `select`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Something like?

```
select t.*, round(dbms_random.value() * 8) + 1 from foo t;
```

Edit:
David has pointed out this gives uneven distribution for 1 and 9.

As he points out, the following gives a better distribution:

```
select t.*, floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) from foo t;
```

Comment: The dbms_random.value(1,9) syntax is still correct. It's just the subquery structure that's wrong

Comment: Ah, not an even distribution of values though.

Comment: Thanks David. I think switching to trunc may give a better distribution

Answer (score 21):

At first I thought that this would work:

```
select DBMS_Random.Value(1,9) output
from   ...
```

However, this does not generate an even distribution of output values:

```
select output,
       count(*)
from   (
       select round(dbms_random.value(1,9)) output
       from   dual
       connect by level <= 1000000)
group by output
order by 1

1   62423
2   125302
3   125038
4   125207
5   124892
6   124235
7   124832
8   125514
9   62557
```

The reasons are pretty obvious I think.

I'd suggest using something like:

```
floor(dbms_random.value(1,10))
```

Hence:

```
select output,
       count(*)
from   (
       select floor(dbms_random.value(1,10)) output
       from   dual
       connect by level <= 1000000)
group by output
order by 1

1   111038
2   110912
3   111155
4   111125
5   111084
6   111328
7   110873
8   111532
9   110953
```

Comment: dbms_random.value(1, 10) is probably more correct as the result x is greater than or equal to the first argument and less than the second according to the [10.2 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i998095)

Answer (score 7):

you don’t need a `select … from dual`, just write:

```
SELECT t.*, dbms_random.value(1,9) RandomNumber
  FROM myTable t
```

Comment: Ah, great. And how do I generate random integers from 1 to 9 instead of floating ?

Comment: use round … aaah, too late :(

Answer (score 6):

If you just use round then the two end numbers (1 and 9) will occur less frequently, to get an even distribution of integers between 1 and 9 then:

```
SELECT MOD(Round(DBMS_RANDOM.Value(1, 99)), 9) + 1 FROM DUAL
```

Comment: An easier way to get an even distribution is to use `floor`