# Rand in select statement

Tags: oracle

The output of my sql select statement is a list of Customer ID in column A.
In column B i want to randomly assign each cust ID either bucket A or B to perform A/B testing. 
How do I use rand to generate a or b in a new column in my select statement

Answer (score 1):

You could use a solution like the one here:
[Generating Random Number In Each Row In Oracle Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568630/generating-random-number-in-each-row-in-oracle-query) which was addressing issues with the use of dbms_random.value.

If you want to get a value that is either 0 or 1, then you can do that like this, assuming your customers are coming from a table named customers:

```
SELECT customer_id, FLOOR(dbms_random.value+0.5)
FROM customers
```

The random value is between 0 and 1 (including 0 and not including 1) so adding 0.5 and using floor means you will get half 0's and half 1's.

Notes on using dbms_random in Oracle 11g are available in their manual here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_random.htm

You may need to initialize the seed to guarantee or improve randomness.

And if 0 and 1 are not appropriate, you could then wrap the FLOOR in a CASE or DECODE to turn the numbers 0 and 1 into the letters A and B.