# Insert random strings,numbers. And result of multiplication

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it real ?

I want insert into this table for column 'valname' strings which    will be (USD,EUR,RUB) 10000times in random order.

In 2nd column 'ammount'
    insert       random numbers from 100-2000. (10000times)

In 3d column
    'should'       represent result of multiplication ammount 
( if usd * 69) (if EUR
    * 72) (if RUB      * 1.2)

For example

```
valname = USD, ammount = 100, converted_ammount = 6900;
valname = EUR, ammount = 100, converted_ammount = 7200;
valname = RUB, ammount = 100,converted_ammount = 120;
```

connect by level <= 10000;

```
    CREATE table t_test01 (    valname varchar2(5),    
ammount number null,    converted_ammount number null --- by multiplication
    * 69,72,1.2    )
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568630/generating-random-number-in-each-row-in-oracle-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into t_test01
 with x as (select case trunc(dbms_random.value*3) 
                     when 0 then 'EUR' 
                     when 1 then 'USD' 
                     else 'RUB' end currency,
             round(dbms_random.value(100,2000)) ammount
             from dual connect by rownum<=10000)
  select currency, ammount, 
         ammount* case currency 
            when 'USD' then 69 
            when 'EUR' then 72 
            else 1.2 end converted_ammount
    from x;
```