# Random number in range - sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query. It will take employee IDs from a table, and assign random numbers between 1-45 in whole number increments. The data is in Oracle - sql.

Comment: I have tried to use DBMS.RANDOM but doesnt seem to provide me a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568679/2630032

Comment: got it.. it worked thank you

Answer (score 5):

Got it:

```
round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 45))
```

round helps me get whole numbers.

Comment: As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568630/generating-random-number-in-each-row-in-oracle-query), you should use `floor` instead of `round` to ensure a better distribution.