# Why does dbms_random.value return the same value in graph queries (connect by)?

Tags: sql, oracle, random

On Oracle 11.2.0.4.0, when I run the following query then each row gets a different result:

```
select r.n from (
  select trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 100)) n from dual
) r
connect by level < 100; -- returns random values
```

But as soon as I use the obtained random value in a join or subquery then each row gets the same value from `dbms_random.value`:

```
select r.n, (select r.n from dual) from (
  select trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 100)) n from dual
) r
connect by level < 100; -- returns the same value each time
```

Is it possible to make the second query return random values for each row?

## UPDATE

My example was maybe over-simplified, here's what I am trying to do:

```
with reservations(val) as (
  select 1 from dual union all
  select 3 from dual union all
  select 4 from dual union all
  select 5 from dual union all
  select 8 from dual
)
select * from (
  select rnd.val, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF leaf from (
    select trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) val from dual
  ) rnd
  left outer join reservations res on res.val = rnd.val
  connect by res.val is not null
)
where leaf = 1;
```

But with reservations which can go from 1 to 1.000.000.000 (and more).
Sometimes that query returns correctly (if it immediately picked a random value for which there was no reservation) or give an out of memory error because it always tries with the same value of `dbms_random.value`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating Random Number In Each Row In Oracle Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568630/generating-random-number-in-each-row-in-oracle-query)

Comment: @user7294900 no, I don't believe those cases are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment "...and I want to avoid concurrency problems" made me think.

Why don't you just try to insert a random number, watch out for duplicate violations, and retry until successful? Even a very clever solution that looks up available numbers might come up with identical new numbers in two separate sessions. So, only an inserted and committed reservation number is safe.

Comment: That could simplify a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the connect-by clause inside the subquery:

```
select r.n, (select r.n from dual) from (
  select trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 100)) n from dual
  connect by level < 100
) r;

         N (SELECTR.NFROMDUAL)
---------- -------------------
        90                  90
        69                  69
        15                  15
        53                  53
         8                   8
         3                   3
...
```

> what I try to do is generate a sequence of random numbers and find the first one for which I don't have a record in some table

You could potentially do something like:

```
select r.n
from (
  select trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 100)) n from dual
  connect by level < 100
) r
where not exists (
  select id from your_table where id = r.n
)
and rownum = 1;
```

but it will generate all 100 random values before checking any of them, which is a bit wasteful; and as you might not find a gap in those 100 (and there may be duplicates within those hundred) you either need a much larger range which is also expensive, though doesn't need to be so many random calls:

```
select min(r.n) over (order by dbms_random.value) as n
from (
  select level n from dual
  connect by level < 100 -- or entire range of possible values
) r
where not exists (
  select id from your_table where id = r.n
)
and rownum = 1;
```

Or repeat a single check until a match is found.

Another approach is to have a look-up table of all possible IDs with a column indicating if they are used or free, maybe with a bitmap index; and then use that to find the first (or any random) free value. But then you have to maintain that table too, and update atomically as you use and release the IDs in your main table, which means making things more complicated and serialising access - though you probably can't avoid that anyway really if you don't want to use a sequence. You could probably use a materialised view to simplify things.

And if you have a relatively small number of gaps (and you really want to reuse those) then you could possibly only search for a gap within the assigned range and then fall back to a sequencer if there are no gaps. Say you only have values in the range 1 to 1000 currently used, with a few missing; you could look for a free value in that 1-100 range, and if there are none then use a sequence to get 1001 instead, rather than always including your entire possible range of values in your gap search. That would also fill in gaps in preference to extending the used range, which may or may not be useful. (I'm not sure if "I don't need those numbers to be consecutive" means they should *not* be consecutive, or that it doesn't matter).

Unless you particularly have a business need to fill in the gaps and for the assigned values to not be consecutive, though, I'd just use a sequence and ignore the gaps.

Comment: Well, I may have over-simplified my example: what I try to do is generate a sequence of random numbers and find the first one for which I don't have a record in some table that is related (so I won't really use a connect condition on the level). For example, I can have reservations from 1 to 1.000.000.000 and I want to find a reservation number which is not currently being used. I am not using a sequence because I don't need those numbers to be consecutive, they can be reused after a while and I want to avoid concurrency problems.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to obtain a correct result with the following query but I am not sure if this approach is really advisable:

```
with
  reservations(val) as (
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 3 from dual union all
    select 4 from dual union all
    select 5 from dual union all
    select 8 from dual
  ),
  rand(v) as (
    select trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) from dual
  ),
  next_res(v, ok) as (
    select v, case when exists (select 1 from reservations r where r.val = rand.v) then 0 else 1 end from rand
  ),
  recursive(i, v, ok) AS (
    select 0, 0, 0 from dual
    union all
    select i + 1, next_res.v, next_res.ok from recursive, next_res where i < 100 /*maxtries*/ and recursive.ok = 0
)
select v from recursive where ok = 1;
```