# Generate series of integers with random start and end SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to generate a series of integers that go from a random start-point until a random (greater) end-point. Furthermore, I would like to do this as a window function, so I could use this in a `OVER (PARTITION BY )` statement.

Basically I'm trying to select random hours (from 1-24), but in a random way and also consecutively, and do this for each client (which is why I suggest an `OVER (PARTITION BY client)` statement, but I'm open for other ideas.

I am trying to use:

```
SELECT
    T1.HOURS
FROM (
        SELECT
            LEVEL HOURS
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY
            LEVEL <= 24
    ) T1,
     (
        SELECT
            INIT,
            LEAST(INIT + LENGTH, 24) FIN
        FROM (
            SELECT
                ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 24)) INIT,
                ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 24)) LENGTH
            FROM DUAL
        ) T0
    ) T2
WHERE
    T1.HOURS >= T2.INIT AND
    T1.HOURS <= T2.FIN;
```

But the result is unfortunately non-consecutive orders.
|hours|
|-----|
|17|
|18|
|20|
|24|

The code is simply nor working because the table T0 (which is the one that filters the initial `INIT` and final `FIN` value) is being replicated for each row.

This is a desired result:

| client | hours |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 13 |
| 3 | 14 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 3 | 16 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 3 | 19 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 3 | 21 |

In the desired result a consecutive list is selected for each client, with a random start and end point.

Comment: Where is CLIENT value coming from? Which database do you use? You tagged PostgreSQL and Oracle SQL Developer (which is a tool), but - final solution probably depends on database, not a tool.

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568630/generating-random-number-in-each-row-in-oracle-query

Comment: The client comes from another table, but in this one I have not implemented that part yet, since I am not even able to generate a list of random-consecutive integers. It could be a foo table though. Couldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can use a correlated `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT c.id,
       h.hours
FROM   ( SELECT id,
                FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 25)) AS bound1,
                FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 25)) AS bound2
         FROM   clients
       ) c
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEAST(bound1, bound2) + LEVEL - 1 AS hours
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ABS(bound1 - bound2) + 1
       ) h;
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE clients (id) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

May (randomly) output:

| ID | HOURS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 19 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 21 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 2 | 24 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 3 | 13 |
| 3 | 14 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 3 | 16 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1udBCpb6)